# Install Samba in Fedora -- for Dummies

Tags: samba

I'm currently using Parallels so that I have Windows XP (host) and Fedora 8 (guest). I like to share folders between the two OS. Parallels has a feature that allows to share folders only if the guest is Windows XP. So, given this situation, I'm exploring the possibility of installing samba but I just could not understand how to do it.

I've been googling on how to install samba but just couldn't understand it. Is there a simplest way of installing samba for a newbie?

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to install the samba client? (though I suspect this is already installed):

```
 yum install samba-client
```

Or the samba server?

```
 yum install samba
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing samba [if required, use yum install samba], you will need to make sure that you have a non root user account created on the Fedora box (use the same username that you login to windows with to make this simple). Then, as root, use pdbedit to add yourself to the smb passwd list:

```
pdbedit -a -u username
```

and type in your windows password, twice.

Then check your smb.conf file (it should be in /etc/samba/smb.conf or /etc/smb.conf) and make sure that that it has a line that reads:

```
security = user
```

Then scroll down to the Share Definitions section and uncomment the homes section to share you Fedora home directory. You will see several examples of how to setup shares. Then start the samba process with:

```
service smbd start
```

Answer (score 0):

yum install samba {server/client}

from fc8 u can start service smb restart

Comment: I did the yum install samba for the server and client... it's the next step that I'm missing on how to make it connect with Windows or vice-versa... I'm not very familiar with networking in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for newbie is not to install samba server at all. You can share your folders in Windows and access them from linux through Nautilus. Just type `smb://host/share` in your file browser and use it.

Answer (score 0):

both place win and linux u need to create a folder share that it once u service restart smb it will able to copy paste from both end..

Answer (score 0):

To install samba you just need to do the commands listed by Matt Simmons, once you have that part you will most likely want to look at some examples of the configuration file which is normally located as /etc/smb.conf in my experience...

If you google samba conf you should find some nice examples making a simple share, for example [Here](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/samba/)

Depending on your system, how secure you will need to make it, if your just testing you could just open it up and then lock down once you know the shares work.

Sorry this is a bit vague but hope it gets you in the right direction.